# How to change data in sorted set?

Tags: redis, node-redis, phpredis

I use sorted set data type in Redis.
I add data with command `zadd`. Adding data is JSON format.

How I can change value in this sorted set by score?
I need get JSON value and change one field and after update this sorted set.

I tried to add againg data with the same score, but I get dublicates

Comment: Seem if value is different Redis adds new element in sorte set with the same `score` (:

Comment: Of course. How can redis know that you're referring to an existing member if you sent a different one? Also you should check the XX option on [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/zadd)

Comment: Then how to change data? I add data like as: `zadd(key, score, data)`. After I get data by `score` and try to update `data`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's simple!

```
ZREM key data;
ZADD key score newdata;
```

You simply cannot UPDATE an element in SET structure. It's not possible by definition! Like I cannot EAT a cup of water, I can only DRINK it ^_^

Reply if you have any further problems.

By the way, I don't know your application need, but I have a strong feeling that SORTED SET is unsuitable for your application senario.

Comment: i am storing time series data and each time i fetch new candles, the last 2 stored candles change, i am using a sorted set with timestamp as the score and everything else as the data item itself, but each time i add 3 new candles, 2 candles already exist, should i delete them and add the new ones or is there no concept of updates in sorted set?

Answer (score 4):

One does not update a set's (sorted or not) members. You'll have to remove the old member and add the new (updated JSON) in its place with the relevant score. You could wrap this in Lua or a WATCH/MULTI/EXEC block for atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove first by score if you're using the list as a key (score) => value store.

```
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE key score score
ZADD key score data
```